# Composer dump-autoload showing error even after downgrading PHP and running composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

My client has a laravel 7 project hosted within a sub-folder on a shared host. Everything was alright until recently the host company upgraded to php v8.1.12 resulting in error when using `composer dump-autoload`. I have been able to reverse the php version for the specific project to 7.4 and even 7.3. But at each attempt to run `composer update` the composer loads correctly but when it reaches `Generating optimized autoload files` I get this error:

`Deprecation Notice: Return type of  Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in  /home1/rootfolder/public_html/projectfolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1270 Deprecation Notice: Return type of  Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home1/rootfolder/public_html/projectfolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1281 Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the  [\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home1/rootfolder/public_html/projectfolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1293 Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /home1/rootfolder/public_html/projectfolder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1306 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi`

When I `php --version` I get:

`PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2022 17:42:02) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.3.33, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with the ionCube PHP Loader + ionCube24 v10.4.5,`
`Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by ionCube Ltd. with Zend OPcache v7.3.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies`

I have read as much as 50 articles pointing at the similar problem here on SO, and i have additionally explored more questions and answers outside SO yet non have enabled me resolve my problem since the past 2 days. Below are my attempts:

Changed Composer from

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5"
```

to

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5|^8.1.12"
```

and

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5"
```

Run `composer update` without deleting composer.lock

Run `composer install` without deleting composer.lock

Run `composer self-update` without deleting composer.lock

Deleted composer.lock and run `composer update`

Deleted composer.lock and run `composer install`

Deleted composer.lock and run `composer self-update`

Run `composer clear cache`

Contacting support, and the list goes on and on.

With everything I do, it seems composer continues to recognise v8.1.12 as the current php, although this is only set to the homedirectory which the host support team clearly says can not be changed because that is automatically set to the highest PHP available. And the weird thing is I also see Composer creates a fold on the homedirectory `.Composer` but the project is on a subfolder with its unique domain name. I am not very good with Laravel, PHP, and Composer but some guidance will do.

My last option maybe upgrading the entire project which is quite tricky as it involves various dependencies that are currently not fully optimized for Laravel 8 or 9

Comment: `composer.lock` defines what to install when running `composer install`, simple as that. Use that to install the dependencies that you had there previously. You can delete the verdor dir completely and restore it that way. `composer update` is simply not the right tool for that. That error that you quote has been mentioned here more than once already, so there shouldn't be any questions left. BTW: If that doesn't help, please extract a [mcve] from your project.

Comment: @Ulrich Thanks for reaching out and also educating me more on composer. But I am sure if you took some time to read my question in between you will find the problem. But users request more details when you provide less, and less details when you provide more. In honesty, it's about the patience and time "we don't always seem to have". Thus most help on SO today are predominantly history based( wasn't this way 10yrs ago). So I understand. BTW: I am not going to ask a bunch of guys to vote my question to gain the users attention SO users seems to like :) Funny but === 1